# Image zoom vs cut in Twenty Seventeen header image

Tags: header-image, theme-twenty-seventeen

I am using the Twenty Seventeen theme and am trying to control the behavior of the header image/media for different screen resolutions/sizes.

The standard seems to be just cutting the picture and changing the proportions when changing to lower resolutions screen. Instead I would like it to "zoom", keeping the same proportions as for the full screen layout.
This already seems to be the standard for the panel images.

I played with a bunch of css settings, but just can't seem to find the right one...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this javascript library [imagefill](http://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/)
demo [here](https://omanko.ru/) 2nd section "Новости"